# Trying to load a pandas df into an already created table in a SQL server database. I am able to connect and create a new table but unable to load df

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, mysql-error-1064

Trying to load a pandas df into an already created table in a SQL server database. I am able to connect and create a new table but unable to load a df
My code is here:

```
# Dependencies
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import urllib

# Variables
server = 'My_Server\SQLEXPRESS'
database = 'My_db'

# Connect to sql db
conn_str = (
    r'Driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;'
    r'Server=My_Server\SQLEXPRESS;'
    r'Database=My_db;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
quoted_conn_str = urllib.parse.quote_plus(conn_str)
engine = create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={quoted_conn_str}')

cnxn = engine.connect()

# Load df to sql db 
My_df.to_sql(name = 'myTable1', con = cnxn, if_exists = 'append',index = False)
cnxn.close()
```

Here's the error I get:
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]String or binary data would be truncated in table 'representation_v1.dbo.RepresentationTable1', column 'Country'. Truncated value: '\xa0'. (2628) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated. (3621)")
[SQL: INSERT INTO [RepresentationTable1] ([Country], [countryCode], [Population], [LHR], [UHR], [CPRLH], [CPRUH], [Groups]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)].......

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLR4j.png)

Comment: What's the collation of the destination column, `representation_v1.dbo.RepresentationTable1.Country`? It may be using a collation that does not support the `0xA0` code point, e.g.: code page 950.

Comment: I figured it out! It seems when I created my table, I didn't specify the no. of characters for the Varchar types (I thought the default would be sufficient). I re-created my table setting Varchar (128) and now I'm able to load data. I think that's what the error message was referring to when it say "...column 'Country'. Truncated value: '\xa0'. (2628)..."

Answer (score 0):

the error message that says "...column 'Country'. Truncated value: '\xa0'. (2628)..." suggests that the no. of characters in my data for the 'Country' column is too much for the no. of characters I set up in the country column and was at risk of being truncated hence the error.
Deleting the table and recreating it and allowing more characters in the column (Varchar (128)) fixed the problem.